# How do I write a do while loop to ask user to enter numbers and terminate the loop when the number entered is 0

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int num=0;
        do{
            if(num!=0)
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            num=input.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        while(num==0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compile this code? Where are your `{ }` brackets after your `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fixed your exit condition inside `while()`
For condition `num != 0` this loop will be executed as long as num is **not equal zero**.

Additionaly read about java conventions, just about spaces and etc, to make your code much more readable and clear: [link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-whitespace.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
    } while (num != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`do loop` runs until the condition in while loop is `false`. Therefor, whenever user gives `0` it `breaks` the loop;

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num=0;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
    }
    while(num != 0);
}
```